# How to setup fake raid for vmware virtual machines?

Tags: raid, vmware-esxi, software-raid, fakeraid

I have a vmware esxi 5 running on a server with ssd and two hard drives. The server comes with software lsi megaraid and intel rapid storage raid. Neither of them work with esxi.

I need to somehow setup a fakeraid inside virtual machine to keep a copy data on each drive (raid0).

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I must of been tired when posting this questions but I should clear something out. The questions is about setting up fakeraid for virtual machine or guest-os.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ESXi is not supporting fake raid. You need to create 2 VMFS and add 2 disk each on one of the data stores and setup software RAID on the guest OS. You will have redundancy for VM, but not for ESX itself.

Comment: If you go this route, another option would be to expose the disks to a VM as raw block devices (instead of adding the extra VMFS layer) with `vmkfstools --createrdmpassthru`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but this is what worked for me. Thank you Mircea and Shane

Answer (score 5):

You should use supported hardware. Fakeraid solutions aren't in the scope of VMWare ESXi blessed setup. You can make things work by acquiring a hardware RAID controller from the [VMWare Hardware Compatibility List](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://www.vmware.com/go/hcl&ei=VdhkT7biNYTc0QHg89jTBw&usg=AFQjCNEXuH3H1BNILfm7AMoBNO0jQXhT-g), though.